# Is is possible to make all flex items the same width in a column layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
column {display: flex; flex-direction: column}
column > * {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<column>
  <flex1>1234567890</flex1>
  <flex2>abc</flex2>
  <flex3>...random length...</flex3>
</column>
```

Above doesn't accomplish what I like to do.

Comment: The `flex` property, and its component long-hand properties, work only along the main axis. Because you're in a column-direction container, the main axis is vertical, and `flex: 1` affects height, not width.

Comment: The question isn't formulated well, by default all items have the same width, when using column, as we can clearly see in your example.

Comment: @Michael_B I know that

Comment: @VXp see Temani Afif's answer.

Comment: Yes, like I said, you should have written something like "how to make them take the width of the widest content", not just same width which already is, by default, and I know about the inline-flex solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inline-flex` and `width:100%` for the flex items:

```css
column {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

column>* {
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<column>
  <flex1>1234567890</flex1>
  <flex2>abc</flex2>
  <flex3>...random length...</flex3>
</column>
```

Answer (score -1):

'Same width in a column layout' , I think this is it..

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1234567890</div>
  <div>abc</div>
  <div>...random length...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. Don't know if it answers the OP's question but i like the answer :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: No, you have to use flex-column layout.